# Windows 8.1 after unlocking screen windows are all in one screen

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro with 2 monitors. Most of the time, I am in "Desktop" mode. I have my open windows spread between the two monitors. Some windows in one screen and some windows in the other screen.

If I lock the screen (Win + L) and leave it locked for a short while (lets say to make a coffee), then when I unlock it, all my windows seem to come have been moved into one monitor. I again have to spread them out. Very frustrating. But if I lock and unlock immediately, then they all seem fine.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try temporarily disabling power-saving features (that could turn-off your monitor) both in windows and  [if any]  in your monitor on-screen configuration menus and check if this is the source of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are your monitors connected with a DisplayPort connection? When monitors are powered down, either manually or by power-management, the display settings adapt, and move all windows to the main display.

nVidia graphic drivers offer a way to copy the monitor's EDID data and load it from disc, allowing to keep the display settings when a monitor powers down. Intel graphic drivers recently are supposed to allow EDID overrides, but I don't know how. ([I'm trying to find out here](https://superuser.com/questions/1241417/intel-graphics-windows-how-to-configure-a-fixed-edid))